# Having problems installing icedtea on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, java, firefox, plugin

I'm changing over from Oracle Java to OpenJDK. I ripped out all traces of Java from the system regardless of vendor and started from scratch. I downloaded the latest OpenJDK tarball and put it in /opt/java/latest. Everything runs fine except for Java content in Firefox.

I also went to http://icedtea.wildebeest.org/download/icedtea-web-binaries/1.8/linux/ to download icedtea so I can get the java plugin which Firefox can use.

After unpacking the zip, icedteaplugin.so is missing from icedtea-web-image/lib

Since the URL I posted above didn't work, what site does one go to get the icedteaplugin.so?

Please, no "run yum install..." replies. There are very good reasons why I'm setting this up manually.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, support for OpenJDK and JAVA, along with other NPAPI plugins like Flash etc., has been dropped from most current browsers for security and privacy reasons. Check the link below for reference:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI#Support/deprecation

Still about the NPAPI support, on that same article there's a list of other browsers that still support those plugins. From that list, Waterfox is one really close to Firefox - in fact, it's Firefox-based, and still supports JAVA - which means it can also support OpenJDK as well.